# How do I have a left div shift to the top when the page shrinks?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently, I'm designing my website and having a bit of trouble with the placement of my components. I currently have two main divs on my homepage, one of which is a fixed sidebar (Info) and the other is for content (Content). I want to make it so that when the window width shrinks, my divs don't get squished together. Ideally the sidebar (Info) moves to the top of the screen and my content (Content) moves beneath it. Attached is an image that describes my current setup as well as what I want to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: While there are other ways, usually we use [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).

Comment: Looks promising. I will look into it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way that I found to do it,

```css
    #info{
        position:fixed;
        height:100vh;
        width:25vw;
    }
  
    #content{
        margin-left:25vh;
        height:100vh;
    }

    @media (max-width:800px) {
        .app #info {
            position:relative;
            display:block;
            height:30%;
        }
    }
    @media (max-width:800px) {
        .app #content {
            display:block;
            margin-left:0px;
            width:25vw;
        }
    }
```

I added an id to the info and content sections to format them separately and used media queries (`@media`) to change the way styles of the divs once the screen hit a certain width. I chose `max-width:800px` arbitrarily, but you can change it to whatever suits your needs best.

Answer (score 1):

The following media queries may be what your need:

```
@media (orientation: landscape){
   ...................
} 
@media (orientation: portrait){
   ...................
}
```